# komapping fromjs exclude property from converting into observable inside elements of array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, mapping, komapping

I am trying to perform conversion of property to observable with the use of komapping plugin.

I do have array of same kind of objects like below:

```
 var data =[{ b1: "v1", b2: "b21" }, { b1: "v2", b2: "b22" }] ;
```

Now I wanted to property b1 as if and b2 to be converted to observable with the use of komapping. For simplicity I have kept here only two properties but in realty I do have more properties.

so I tried it like following:

```
var data = [{ b1: "v1", b2: "b21" }, { b1: "v2", b2: "b22" }] ;
var result = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { copy: "b1" });
console.log(result());
```

But it does not work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmo7ejsk/) is the jsfiddle

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your current mapping options only check for a `b1` property name in the first data you pass, i.e.: the data array.

One way to fix this (maybe not the easiest, I'm not sure), is to define how to process each item:

```
var data = [{ b1: "v1" }, { b1: "v2" }];

var result = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
    create: function(options) {
      var nestedData = options.data;
      return ko.mapping.fromJS(nestedData, { 'copy': 'b1' });
    }
});
```

Each item in `data` is passed to the `create` method inside `options.data` (the original data remains accessible through either `data` or `options.parent`).

The create function returns a mapped object using the mapping you originally tried.

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ftk3a03/